# Zend Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sql-update

How to write below mysql query using zend syntax?

```
UPDATE core_user_transaction as t 
JOIN core_user_transaction_therapy AS cuts ON cuts.tid=t.tid
JOIN therapy_booking AS tb ON cuts.conf_id = tb.conf_id
JOIN therapy_service_fees AS fees ON cuts.fee_id=fees.id
JOIN therapy_service_taxes AS tst ON fees.service_id=tst.service_id
JOIN core_tax AS ct ON ct.tax_id = tst.tax_id
SET t.tax=ROUND(t.fee*(ct.tax_value/100),2),
    t.amount = (ROUND(t.fee*(ct.tax_value/100),2)+t.fee)
WHERE tb.datetime >= '2015-10-01 00:00:00'
    AND t.state = 'PENDING'
    AND t.status ='ACTIVE'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible with the 'update()' method provided by the Zend Db Adapter.
You can however, run the query manually using the adapter. Something like:

```
    // $adapter is an instance of Zend_Db_Adapter
    $adapter->query(YOUR QUERY HERE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$adapter = new Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter($driverConfig);
$sql = "YOUR_QUERY";
$statement = $adapter->query($sql);
$statement->execute();
```

Also please refer [Zend\Db\Adapter](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.db.adapter.html)